# Is symbian s60 3rd FP2 edition is backward compatible with s30 2nd edition FP3?

Tags: java-me, sdk, symbian, compatibility, nokia

I have developed application in `symbian s60 3rd fp2`, I want to tun it in nokia `N72` that requires `symbian s60 2nd edition fp3`, so do I required to make different builds or its backward compatible to `2nd edition fp3`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is not backwards compatible. S60 3rd edition is based on Symbian 9, and S60 2nd edition fp3 is based on Symbian 8. Symbian 8 and 9 are binary incompatible.  The good news is that the platform security concept was not yet introduced on S60 2nd edition so the porting work should be fairly easy.

Comment: Hi this answer is not correct. You are mixing the Symbian^3 and S60 3rd, which is based on the Symbian OS v9.3!!!

Comment: Symbian 8 and Symbian 9 are binary incompatible. A Symbian 8 app will not work on a Symbian 9 system and reversed. A special build is required.

Answer (score 1):

the `S60 3rd FP2` is based on the `Symbian OS v9.3`, while the `S60 2nd FP3` is based on the `Symbian OS 8.0a` or `8.1` if I remember and it is really, really old version. The source code will be more or less compatible, but you will need to make certain changes especially to prepare the sis file, since e.g. application resource, icon format and the application binary format (exe vs. app) changed...

I suggest you to not try to support those old phones... I am not even sure if the SDK is still available for the download and you might not be allowed to go to the Ovi store with that. but I am not sure here - check it on your own.

BR
STeN